# Java long object array assignment time difference

Tags: java

I have a piece of the source code in java8:

```java
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


       testObject(1.3);
       testObject(1.4);
    }



    private static void testObject(double num) {
       System.out.println("test:" + num);
       long sta = System.currentTimeMillis();
       int size = 10000000;
       Object[] o = new Object[(int) (size * num)];
       for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
           o[i] = "" + i;
       }
      System.out.println("object[]: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - sta) + " ms");
   }
}
```

execution Result:

```
test:1.3
object[]: 7694 ms
test:1.4
object[]: 3826 ms
```

Why is the running time so different when my quantity is 1.4 * size？

I wanted to see how Java array assignment works, but I couldn't find anything on google.

Comment: have you tried to invert the call order? like put the `test(1.4)` before `test(1.3)`.

Comment: You're not measuring what you think you are measuring - you are observing JVM warmup or some other effect, most likely. Benchmarking java code is very difficult - you have to eliminate hotspot warmup, optimization, etc. Follow [this JMH tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-microbenchmark-harness).

Comment: I have tried to run 1.3 and 1.4 separately and still get different results.As you said, JVM warm-up or some other effect interfered with my testing.

Answer (score 1):

In addition you have to keep in mind that System.currentTimeMillis returns a "Wall-Clock-Time". If your OS does a reschedule during the `for`-loop and a different process gets the cpu, the Wall-Clock-Time increases but your program won't execute.